# Fetching Pruchase Order {"There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."} in QBO API

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, quickbooks-online, purchase-order

var pos = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.PurchaseOrder();
var Poos = commonService.FindAll(pos, 1, 10).ToList();

{"There is an error in XML document (0, 0)."}

Intuit.Ipp.Exception.SerializationException

Can anybody help me on this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please add more information. Things like what you're trying to do, how you're doing it, what data you're working with, what output you expect, what output you're actually getting etc. Without that it's hard to try and figure out what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

In the raw response XML, there are some non-xml or control characters which are causing devkit's XML de-serializer fail.

You can enable the devkit's logger to grab the raw response. You can copy-paste it in any UTF-8 enabled editor to see which character was causing this issue.

If it is something related to raw data (the data which you have in QBO), then please correct that from QBO UI.

PN - Ideally, server should handle the non-XML or special characters but this fix is still not in place.

Thanks